# Checking for last double clicked element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there a way to check for the last double clicked element with jQuery. I've made
a table and I want to know how to identify the most recent double clicked `<td></td>` in my code. I tired something like this:

```
var clickedTD = $("td").dblclick;
```

But It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.dblclick()` should work provided the DOM is loaded... See the example below...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //set up dblclick event on the table data elements
  $("td").dblclick(function(){
    //$(this) use key word this for the element clicked
    $("#display").text(`You double clicked: ${$(this).text()}`)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Click 1</td>
    <td>Click 2</td>
    <td>Click 3</td>
    <td>Click 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think jQuery is necessary for this:

```
<td>onclick="checkClick(this)"></td>
function checkClick(clickedElement) {
var clickCount= clickCount + 1;
  if(clickCount === 2){
    console.log(clickedElement);//Last clickedclicked
    }
}
```